# Logging to remote server with OpenTSDB

Tags: java, jar, opentsdb

I am rewriting a service originally written in Python. The service has a socket connection to a remote server running OpenTSDB, where it logs various time series data.

The rewrite is in Java. What is the best approach to replacing the logging from the old service?

When I was Googling, I found [this explanation](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/opentsdb/jx0JIPadDXk/Je4GTCysc-8J) but could not find the opentsdb.jar that was mentioned. Ideally, I would just be able to include the jar in Maven.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your best bet is using Java classes to open an HTTP connection to OpenTSDB and then send data using json, as explained in its documentation:

http://opentsdb.net/docs/build/html/api_http/put.html

The API is really simple, and you'd just have to POST something like this to record data in OpenTSDB (from the link above):

```
[
    {
        "metric": "sys.cpu.nice",
        "timestamp": 1346846400,
        "value": 18,
        "tags": {
           "host": "web01",
           "dc": "lga"
        }
    },
    {
        "metric": "sys.cpu.nice",
        "timestamp": 1346846400,
        "value": 9,
        "tags": {
           "host": "web02",
           "dc": "lga"
        }
    }
]
```